# how to separate [String] by "-" and make multiple column on android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm working on a Searchable dictionary. Its Raw database is separated by "-" like

```
ColumnA(Key_Word)     ColumnB(Key_defination)
Apple                 - One kind of Fruit
Mango                 - One fruit also
```

But I want to make it 3 column, (Column C will be Key_details)

```
ColumnA          ColumnB                 ColumnC (Key_details)
Apple          - One kind of Fruit     - Round shape
Mango          - One fruit also        - Found in Bangladesh
```

When people search A, application will show Column B and C. The reason why i splited string is I want to show Coumn B and C on different window.  How to do that? Here is my source-

```
/**
 * Contains logic to return specific words from the dictionary, and
 * load the dictionary table when it needs to be created.
 */
public class DictionaryDatabase {
    private static final String TAG = "DictionaryDatabase";

    //The columns we'll include in the dictionary table
    public static final String KEY_WORD = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
    public static final String KEY_DEFINITION = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dictionary";
    private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTSdictionary";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private final DictionaryOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;
    private static final HashMap<String,String> mColumnMap = buildColumnMap();


    public DictionaryDatabase(Context context) {
        mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DictionaryOpenHelper(context);
    }

    private static HashMap<String,String> buildColumnMap() {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put(KEY_WORD, KEY_WORD);
        map.put(KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_DEFINITION);
        map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
                BaseColumns._ID);
        map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
        map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
        return map;
    }


    public Cursor getWord(String rowId, String[] columns) {
        String selection = "rowid = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {rowId};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);


    }


    public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
        String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
    }


    private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

        Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    private static class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private final Context mHelperContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
        private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                    "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                    " USING fts3 (" +
                    KEY_WORD + ", " +
                    KEY_DEFINITION + ");";

        DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            mHelperContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            mDatabase = db;
            mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
            loadDictionary();
        }

        private void loadDictionary() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        loadWords();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        private void loadWords() throws IOException {
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading words...");
            final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
            InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "-");
                    if (strings.length < 2) continue;
                    long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
                    if (id < 0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                reader.close();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
        }

        public long addWord(String word, String definition) {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_WORD, word);
            initialValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION, definition);

            return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Not clear what your question is.

Comment: The code above make 2 column database Key_word and Key_Definition. I want to make it 3 column. 3rd column name will be Key_Details. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] arr = string.split("-");
```

[String#split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

> Returns the array of strings computed by splitting this string around
>   matches of the given regular expression.

**EDIT:**

```
long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
```

Above line should be:

```
long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim(),strings[2].trim());
```

And change your addWord function as I mentioned below.

```
public long addWord(String word, String definition,String details) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_WORD, word);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION, definition);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DETAILS, details);

        return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Can you please tell me how can i define 3rd column? The code above supossed to have 2 column only Key_word and Key_Definition. I want to add 3rd column Key_Details

Comment: @Tanzil where you want to insert 3rd column . In file or in array ?

Comment: My database contains 3rd column on its Raw.text file. But its only showing 2 column on Mobile as 3rd column is not defined. I want to add a code which will define 3rd column as Key_Details from my raw.text file.

Comment: @Tanzil I edited my answer. Try this once and let me know if you having any issue.

Comment: Oww! The only person understand my problem is you! You know you're a genius! I'm gonna try your code, and give you a feedback! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

A better way to handle the tokenization is by using StringTokenizer

```
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(str,"-");
```

To access the tokens,

```
while(token.hasNext())
{
    String tmp = token.nextToken();
    ...
}
```